# How to add a string along with the appendChild?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I add a word in between two appendChild that are list items for example my code is the one below. This shows male 18, I want it to show male - age:18

```
x.appendChild (gender);
x.appendChild(age);
document.getElementById("list").appendChild(x);
```

Comment: If it's a static, use [`after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) or `before`.

Comment: You can't append text between two list items (`li` elements), it's invalid HTML.

Comment: @Teemu, he has not indicated that he is using UL LI, could be using other tags

Comment: @user9879287 It's just a warning, in the case they are using a list element. Actually most of the browsers will allow a text node being put into a list element, but linters won't accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) to add text nodes to an element.

```
x.appendChild (gender);
x.append(" - age:");
x.appendChild(age);
```

Comment: @poni No problem.